# *.sln will build in Xamarin Studio but not in xbuild

Tags: xamarin, xbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains 16 C# projects.  I also have a separate `build.proj` file which contains three `<Target>`s:

- `Build`, which contains an `<MSBuild>` reference to the *.sln
- `Package`, which contains the `<MakeDir>` and `<CopyCommands>` to copy the built DLL/EXE files along with various data files to a `$(StagePath)` directory.
- `Deploy`, that copies files from the stage path to a deploy path.

I was able to run the command `xbuild /t:Deploy build.proj` to build the *.sln and copy its files to the appropriate location, until recently when IT decided to move my Documents folder onto a network drive.

Now, whenever I try to run this xbuild command, I get several errors like the one below.  (The reference is to one of the dependencies within the same solution.)

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Util' does not exist in the namespace `Contoso'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

But whenever I do a “Build All” on the same *.sln from Xamarin Studio, I get a successful build with 0 errors and 0 warnings.  So why can't xbuild find these assembly references if Xamarin Studio can?